# Why does HAML think I have content on the line and nested? (I don't)

Tags: haml

My HAML reads:

```
%table.screenshots
  %thead
    %trow
      %td{:colspan => 12} Screenshots for #{element.name}
  %tbody
    - screenshots.each do |set|
      %tr
        - set[1].each do |shot|
          - if shot == :blank_cell
            %td{:colspan => set[0]}.twelfth &nbsp;
          - else
            %td{:colspan => set[0]}.twelfth
              = image_tag(shot[1]) # <= ERROR APPEARS HERE
              - if @redacted
                %h1.blur
                  %span Image blurred in
                  %br
                  %span demo report only
              %p #{shot[0]}
```

There are no invisible spaces or tabs after `.twelfth`.

Why, then, do I get this error?

```
Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %td and nested within it.
```

BTW, I get the same exception when I run:

```
haml --debug print.html.haml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class and id identifiers (`.` and `#`) must come after the tag name, and before any attribute hash.

In your code the problem is the line:

```
%td{:colspan => set[0]}.twelfth
```

This is interpreted as a `td` element with a `colspan` attribute, containing the content `.twelfth`, which would look like this when rendered, if it were by itself:

```html
<td colspan='7'>.twelfth</td>
```

However this line also has content nested below, which Haml doesn’t allow.

You can fix this by using an explicit `class` entry in the attribute hash as you have in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641533/214790), or by moving the `.twelth` class specifier in front of the attribute hash, like this:

```
%th.twelfth{:colspan => set[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the offending line to:

```
%td{:colspan => set[0], :class => "twelfth"}
```

Looks like there's a bug in the HAML interpreter